# Using C sockets to connect to MYSQL database

Tags: c, sockets, winsock, winsock2

Am writing an application for a Point of Sale TERMINAL , the manual for the terminal restricts direct MYSQL connection from the terminal, All connections should be done using Sockets. How can I connect to a MYSQL database using C sockets? Below is my working C program that establishes a TCP connection to specified ip and port.

```
    /*
     * Create a TCP socket
     * @Author Salim Said
     * Jan 2 2015 17:00hrs
    */

    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<winsock2.h>
    #pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

    int main(int argc , char *argv[])
    {
        WSADATA wsa;
        SOCKET s;
        struct sockaddr_in server;

        printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
        if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
        {
            printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
            return 1;
        }

        printf("Initialised.\n");

        //Create a socket
        if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            printf("Could not create socket : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
        }

        printf("Socket created.\n");


        server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("74.125.235.20");
        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_port = htons( 80 );

        //Connect to remote server
        if (connect(s , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
        {
            puts("connect error");
            return 1;
        }

        puts("Connected successfully");

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Why on Earth are you doing this? MySql does have a C API to do this stuff

Comment: @EdHeal the POS compiler cannot compile MYSQL directly, i have to use sockets!

Comment: @electronicsalim - as mentioned, there is an available API for dealing with MySQL. Some find themselves unable to use it, some prefer not to use it, whatever. Here's some code that doesn't need the MySQL library: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27943/Minimalistic-Driver-less-Native-MySql-Client

Comment: @enhzflep Thanks. i will go through the code.

Comment: What is a POS compiker?

Comment: @EdHeal - Piece of _poo_ compiler perhaps.